# can't change the language on my react-native-datepicker

Tags: javascript, react-native, ecmascript-6, datepicker

I'm using `DatePicker` from `react-native-datepicker`; and can't change the language to french,even though i did `locale="fr"`.

```
<DatePicker
    style={{ width: 200 }}
    date={niassance} //initial date from state
    mode="date" //The enum of date, datetime and time
    locale="fr"
    placeholder="selectionner une date"
    format="DD-MM-YYYY"
    minDate="01-01-1940"
    maxDate="01-01-2019"
    confirmBtnText="Confirm"
    cancelBtnText="Cancel"
    customStyles={{
        dateIcon: {
            position: 'absolute',
            left: 0,
            top: 4,
            marginLeft: 0
        },
        dateInput: {
            marginLeft: 36
        }
    }}
    onDateChange={(niassance) => { setNiassance(niassance) }}
/>
```

My react native version is `"react": "~16.9.0"` and I use `expo` to simulate my app.
i appreciate your help

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Update your package.json as follows:

```
"react-native-datepicker": "git+https://github.com/pablo-albaladejo/react-native-datepicker.git",
```

and run

```
rm -rf node_modules && npm install
```

Then in your code (Edited):

```
<DatePicker
      style={{ width: 200 }}
      date={niassance} //initial date from state
      mode="date" //The enum of date, datetime and time
      locale={'fr'}
      placeholder="selectionner une date"
      format="DD-MM-YYYY"
      minDate="01-01-1940"
      maxDate="01-01-2019"
      confirmBtnText="Confirm"
      cancelBtnText="Cancel"
      customStyles={{
        dateIcon: {
          position: "absolute",
          left: 0,
          top: 4,
          marginLeft: 0,
        },
        dateInput: {
          marginLeft: 36,
        },
      }}
      onDateChange={(niassance) => {
        setNiassance(niassance);
      }}
    />
```

Comment: will this change the look of my date picker?

Comment: I've edit my answer. Just follow the steps and copy paste the Datepicker code :)

Answer (score 0):

I use this approach:

```
import moment from 'moment';
import 'moment/locale/fr'
moment.locale('fr')
```

If you aware about moment https://momentjs.com/.
You just need to install the package and put it in top of the file.

Comment: should i just add those lines to my code? cuz i did and nothing changed

Comment: Is it for Android?